# Python Matrix Multiplication Row by Row with Sample Code

Tags: python, arrays, matrix, multiplication

If i have a code for matrix addition;

```
def VectorAddition (a,b):
    c=[]
    if (len(a)!=len(b)):
        return c
    for i in range(0,len(a)):
        c.append(a[i]+b[i])
    return c

def MatrixAddition (A,B):
    c=[]
    for i in range(len(A)):
        c.append(VectorAddition(A[i],B[i]))
    return c
```

How can i write like this code for multiplication that first row by row multiplication as "VectorMultiplication", after appending rows that created to Matrix as "MatrixMultiplication"?

Could you please help me about that?

Comment: Do you want element wise multiplication?

Comment: I want that row multiplications firstly, after that creation of the matrix with values that multiplied.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your requirement correctly, you can just change the `+` operator to `*`:

```
def VectorMultiplication (a,b):
    c = []
    if (len(a)!=len(b)):
        return c
    for i in range(0,len(a)):
        c.append(a[i]*b[i])
    return sum(c)

def MatrixMultiplicaion (A,B):
    c=[]
    for i in range(len(A)):
        c.append(VectorMultiplication(A[i],B[i]))
    return c
```